# Wrap and unwrap method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a library that will spy on method calls (SinonJS-style). What I want to do is wrap and unwrap a method. To wrap the method, I can just wrap the original method in a block:

```
module Spy
  def on(receiver, msg)
    @original = receiver.method(msg)
    wrapped = Proc.new {|*args| @original}
    receiver.define_singleton_method(msg, wrapped)
  end

  extend self
end

instance = Object.new
Spy.on(instance, :to_s)
```

This works fine, but unwrapping the method is problematic:

```
module Spy
  # Add this to the above

  def restore(receiver, msg)
    receiver.define_singleton_method(msg, @original)
  end
end

instance = Object.new
original = instance.method(:to_s)
Spy.on(instance, :to_s)
Spy.restore(instance, :to_s)
restored = instance.method(:to_s)

original == restored
=> false
original.object_id
=> 70317288647120
restored.object_id
=> 70317302643500
```

In fact, it looks like `Object#method` always returns a new object_id. Is there a way for me to reattach the exact same method to the object? In JS I would just store the function and swap it back into place. Am I misunderstanding something about Ruby? Is there another approach that I can use? I'm really interested in the `==` comparator for testing

Thanks ahead of time!

EDIT:

A boiled down version of what the issue is:

```
irb(main):001:0> receiver = Object.new
=> #<Object:0x007fc4a1939320>
irb(main):002:0> original = receiver.method(:to_s)
=> #<Method: Object(Kernel)#to_s>
irb(main):003:0> original == receiver.method(:to_s)
=> true
irb(main):004:0> receiver.define_singleton_method(:to_s, original)
=> :to_s
irb(main):005:0> original == receiver.method(:to_s)
=> false
irb(main):006:0>
```

Is there another way to reattach a method such that the above would be true?

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that the block you pass to `define_singleton_method` is evaluated in the context of `receiver`, so `@original` will be `nil`.

You can copy the method to a local variable so that the block will be a closure

```
@original = receiver.method(msg)
org = @original
wrapped = Proc.new { |*args| org }
```

Secondly, the object ID of the method is irrelevant and you should actually *expect* it to be different. Look at the method you actually get back:

```
instance.method(:to_s)
#<Method: Object(Kernel)#to_s>

Spy.on(instance, :to_s)
Spy.restore(instance, :to_s)

instance.method(:to_s)
#<Method: #<Object:0x00000001>.to_s>
```

The method changes from `Kernel` to the singleton class! Why would the ID be the same? But this doesn't matter because all you've done is attached the method from `Kernel` to the singleton class, so the same code gets run anyway.

Comment: Ah sorry, my actual code is a bit more complex and I tried to simplify it here but messed it up a bit. The issue boils down to: https://gist.github.com/jbodah/7b456fc975382ddb3ffe It looks like `define_singleton_method` is not the proper way to reattach the method to get that equality test to pass

Comment: Figured it out above. The comment on where the method was defined helped a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Mocha accomplishes this by defining a new method which wraps the original: https://github.com/freerange/mocha/blob/master/lib/mocha/class_method.rb#L75

I'm not 100% satisfied with this solution, but it should do the job in most cases. I'm still interested if I can unattach and reattach a method to an instance

EDIT:

It turns out that I can use `Method#source_location` instead for my tests. When this is spied, it will point to my Spy class, and when it is not spied, it points to the original implementation

EDIT 2:

Looked into Max's comment about where the methods were being defined and dug into Ruby's `Method` object. I eventually settled on `original.owner.instance_eval { define_method msg, wrapped }` to wrap and `original.owner.instance_eval { define_method msg, original }` for the restore. This worked with my original tests of using `Method#==` to test